# Rails custom error pages won't render on Nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx

I am new to Rails and Nginx.  I was asked to add custom error pages to our app.  I found instructions to do so on this site and my custom error pages render just fine locally.  When I go to the url `/no_such_page`, I see the appropriate page.  When I deploy the code to our test server running nginx and try the same url, I see the following instead:

> 500 Internal Server Error
>   If you are the administrator of this website, then please read this web application's log file and/or the web server's log file to find out what went wrong.`

On the nginx server, if I go to the url `\404`, then I do see my page, so I know it renders ok.
Both my local machine and the server are running under the `development` environment.

I've added this to `config\development.rb`:

```
config.consider_all_requests_local = false
config.exceptions_app = self.routes
```

Here is what I've added to `routes.rb`:

```
%w(404 500).each do |code|
    get code, to: "errors#show", :code => code, :via => :all
end
```

and my errors_controller looks like this:

```
class ErrorsController < ApplicationController
    def show
        status_code = params[:code] || 500
        render status_code.to_s
    end
end
```

Does anyone know if there is something special that I need to do in my nginx config to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 500 Internal Server Error If you are the administrator of this website, then please read this web application's log file and/or the web server's log file to find out what went wrong.

This error message is from Rails itself, not from Nginx.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.0.0.1/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb#L15-L22

It means that your custom error page is itself raising an exception, which would lead to an infinite loop of error->show error page->error->show error page->... Rails detects this and halts with the error message you are seeing. Check your logs for this string to see what the error is:

```
Error during failsafe response:
```

Comment: Thank you Matt!  I guess I was caught up on the fact that it was working locally and not on the server so I was blaming nginx.  I found my error logs in `var/log/nginx`, which pointed me toward something I was overlooking.  All set now.